Browser context menu not accessible over Spline component in Next.js
Inside my Next.js app, i added a Spline component like so
const Blob: React.FC<BlobProps>  = ({ setIsBlobLoading }) => {
  const scene = "https://prod.spline.design/0Fktb5VBB3QzS3Aw/scene.splinecode";

  const handleContextMenu = (e: React.MouseEvent) => {
    console.log("right click")
  };

  return (
      <div className="mt-24 lg:mt-0 h-[60%] lg:h-auto" onContextMenu={handleContextMenu}>
        <Suspense fallback={null}>
          <Spline scene={scene} onload={() => setIsBlobLoading(false)} />
        </Suspense>
      </div>
  );
};

The issue is that right clicking over the component doesn't show up the browser's context menu. I added an onContextMenu function and on right click it logs "right click" in the console as expected but the browser's context menu still doesn't appear. I also tried adding a negative z-index to the wrapper div and it gets the context menu to show up on right click but then the mouse follow animation i setup on Spline app doesn't work anymore. Is there a way to get both of those interactions to work?
